# When we use the google protocol buffer, could we modify the generated pb.go file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

For example, is it ok to add an interface or associate a function I created with a struct in the generated pb.go file?

The reason that I want to make these kinds of changes is it would make my code easier to implement. I am not sure if I am allowed to do this since the first commented line in the generated file says "DO NOT EDIT".

Comment: Why would the IDE give you an error? It theoretically could be made to warn you about editing pb generated files, but I wouldn’t expect it to.

Comment: @JimB Sorry about my expression. So am I allowed to make these kinds of change? I wouldn't modify any generated code, but just add interfaces or functions

Comment: If you want to add things, use another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit generated code as much as you want. But It's not recommended because if you compile the code again your changes will be discarded and maybe you face some unexpected bugs.